# Are All Wireless Cards Compatible With the Motherboard? Regardless of What Type of Board and Card it is?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, motherboard, wireless-card

This may sound like a stupid question, and please don't shoot me down for this. But I am thinking of getting a wireless card for my desktop. More specifically, a TP-Link TL-WDN4800 wireless card. I have a MSI MS-7918 Gaming Motherboard. Will this right off the bat be compatible? Or do I have to do deep research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it will fit one of the many internal or external ports on your motherboard.

The TP-Link TL-WDN4800 is a PCI express card.

Your Motherboard has PCI Express cards.

You'lll be fine.